# Installing linux programs when something else has to be installed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

I seem to have all the dependencies to install a program, but I'm getting these error messages.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  rabbitvcs-nautilus3: Depends: nautilus (>= 1:3~) but 1:2.30.1-0ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
                       Depends: python-nautilus (>= 1.0~) but 0.6.1-1 is to be installed
                       Depends: python-gobject (>= 2.28.2~) but 2.21.1-0ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

What does that mean? How can I get this installed?

Comment: Are you using a package manager?

Comment: Can you [edit] and include a `cat /etc/sources.list /etc/sources.list.d/*.list`

Comment: @Paul /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* but for Maverick and above these should be in default repository list. http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rabbitvcs to be exact

Comment: @Karlson what they should be and what they are are separate matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that in the versions of packages from the current cache for `nautilus`, `python-nautilus`, and `python-gobject` are not at the appropriate versions to install the `rabbitvcs-nautilus3`.  The versions needed are indicated in ().

So before doing anything you should do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If the error continues then you should add the sources containing the newer versions of these packages to the sources list.

The locations are:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Normally the location for this package would be the same as the package you are trying to install.